# PHP file not opening

Tags: php

I placed a file on my website server with HTML and PHP in it and named the file 'php1.php'. I tried running the file and all was fine. Later after some time abruptly I got a 500 ERROR and continued to get them despite my site being accessible. Then to test I copied this file with name changed to 'php1.html' and ran the file and the PHP code was being loaded a text. All other PHP files are running well. Other HTML files requiring PHP are kept seperately as two files and only this file has PHP coded with HTML in the same file.

I ran a phpinfo function and got this. http://analyzedstock.com/test/phpinfo.php . Is all fine with the installed PHP? What could be the problem with my file then? I have simple functions to output. The link to my PHP page is here: http://analyzedstock.com/test/PHP/php1.php

Also I would be very thankful if you find any errors in my code. I get ' Log in success. ' at the start of the form.

```
<?PHP

//form variables

$name=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$email=$_POST['email'];

//current

$minname=10;
$minpass=6;
$maxname=15;
$maxpass=10;

//functions

function username($username){
empty($username) || $username<$minname || $username>$maxname;
return username($username);
}

function password($password){
 empty($password) || $password<$minpass || $password>$maxpass;
return password($password);
}

//function email($email){
//    empty($email) || !isset("\@") || !isset(".com");
//}

if(username($username) && password($password)){
 echo"Log in Error!!";
 }else{
echo"Log in success.";
}

?>

<html>
<head>
<title>First try</title>
</head>
<body>

Log In
<form action="php1.php" method="POST">
Username: <input type="text" name="username" /><br />
Password: <input type="password" name="password" /><br />
<!--E-mail: <input type="text" name="email" /><br />-->
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Post the code of 'php1.php'

Comment: You should check your errog log and see why it gives you an error. Also, seeing php code when renaming to html is normal, unless your server is configured to parse html files through php which is a bit of a resources overkill.

Comment: either its the .htaccess file or the error code in the PHP file. change the uppercase might work.. http://analyzedstock.com/test/php/php1.php

Comment: it may redirecting to some other file which does not exists...:)

Comment: @user1844933 No, the messages shows that normally he will try go get the defined 404 file, but because it doesnt exists, a 404 will also be thrown...

Comment: http://analyzedstock.com/test/PHP/errorphp.php  all clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add the following lines to your php file to see what for error you get:

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>
```

Ok the following lines are incorrect:

```
function password($password){
 empty($password) || $password<$minpass || $password>$maxpass;
return password($password);
}
```

**The conditions should between a if condition**

Change to:

```
function username($username){
 if(empty($username) || $username<$minname || $username>$maxname)
    return $username;
}

function password($password){
 if(empty($password) || $password<$minpass || $password>$maxpass)
    return $password;
}
```

And also change PHP to lowercase (what already is said) ==> < ? php

Comment: analyzedstock.com/test/PHP/errorphp.php all clear

Comment: aren't those functions infinite loops, recursion ?

Comment: add `ini_set('display_startup_errors', true);`

Comment: DanFromGermany . .Where should I be pasting the code?

Comment: @AnujSanghvi I changed my code, now you dont get a recursive loop

Answer (score 2):

Infinite recursion, undefined `$minpass`, expecting boolean but returning string/null/infinite, `<` without strlen:

```
function username($username){
    $minname = 8;
    if (empty($username) || $username<$minname || $username>$maxname)
       return username($username);
}

function password($password){
     $minpass = 8;
     if (empty($password) || $password < $minpass || $password > $maxpass) 
        return password($password);
}
```

"return myself, return myself again, return myself again,.. again.. again... 500 times..."

Better:

```
function username($username){
    if (empty($username) || strlen($username)<$minname || strlen($username)>$maxname) 
        return true;
    else return false;
}

function password($password){
     if (empty($password) || strlen($password)<$minpass || strlen($password)>$maxpass) 
        return true;
     else return false;
}
```

Also logical wrong:

```
if(username($username) && password($password)){
```

should be

```
if(username($username) || password($password)){
```

because you want: "if either one of those expressions fail, send error msg"

Answer (score 1):

`<?PHP` should be lower case probably. Also keep eye on url, it is case sensitive also.